# Qt C++: Moving a file, source and destination paths are on different drives

Tags: c++, qt, file

I want to move a file from a folder (say on Drive C) to another folder (say on Drive D) in C++. If, the file is already present in the destination folder, it should overwrite that. How can I achieve it with C++ std libraries or Qt?

I found "rename" method, but I'm not sure that it will work if paths are on different drives. Moreover, what is the platform dependency?

Comment: Does my answer works? :)

Comment: Qt doc says "(bool QFile::rename(const QString & newName))If the rename operation fails, Qt will attempt to copy this file's contents to newName, and then remove this file, keeping only newName.", so I think it should work if drives are different.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [QFile::rename()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html#rename). It should do approximately the right thing, for most purposes. C++ standard library does not have a inter-filesystem rename call I think (please correct me in comments if I am wrong!), [std::rename](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) can only do move inside single filesystem.

However, normally the only (relevant) atomic file operation here is rename within same file system, where file contents are not touched, only directory information changes. I'm not aware of a C++ library which supports this, so here's rough pseudocode:

```
if basic rename succeeds
   you're done
else if not moving between file systems (or just folders for simplicity)
   rename failed
else
   try
     create temporary file name on target file system using a proper system call
     copy contents of the file to the temporary file
     rename temporary file to new name, possibly overwriting old file
     remove original file
   catch error
     remove temporary file if it exists
     rename failed
```

Doing it like this ensures, that file in new location appears are a whole file at once, and worst failure modes involve copying the file instead of moving.

Comment: Considering the Windows drive letters, it may be wise to defer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx): "The new name must not be the name of an existing file or directory. You can use `rename` to move a file from one [...] device to another by giving a different path in the `newname` argument. However, you cannot use `rename` to move a directory."

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will it work if target directory is sitting on a mounted drive? I don't have resources to verify it :(.

Comment: @nik_kgp After a bit of research, it looks like atomic file operations on Windows are quite a complex (or impossible, especially on Windows versions prior to Vista) subject, even more so than on Posix. So the general solution is to not worry about it, just check errors and report as appropriate. Relying on exact file system state is bad idea anyway, since some other program may modify it at the same time. About mounted drives, user could unmount it at any time anyway (or in case of external drive, just yank out the cable). So just use `QFile::rename` and check return code.